# How to use javascript Object in AMD module with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, karma-runner, amd

I have a sample module

```
define([
    'components/user/list/usersList.require',
    'components/user/manage/userManage.require'
], function (usersListRequire, userManageRequire) {
    "use strict";

    var userPath = 'components/user/';
    var userRequire = {
        'UserModule': userPath + 'user.module',
        'UserRoute': userPath + 'user.routes'
    };

    return Object.assign(
        userRequire,
        usersListRequire,
        userManageRequire
    );
});
```

Running tests in Karma I get an error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'Object.assign(
```

I try to use the default JS Object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Does anyone know how to declare that in AMD there was no error? What kind of path to use?

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

> Object.assign is supported by chrome version 45 or later.

If you are using phantomjs for running tests please install latest phantomjs.

Comment: ok, i was install "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.12", but when i start test by Grunt i still see in console INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1]. Where you have to set with which version should I use?